# How to add a custom CSS file to VisualForce?

Tags: visualforce

I have a simple VisualForce code:

```
<apex:page controller="Query_and_upload"  standardStylesheets="True" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
<apex:stylesheet value="{URLFOR($Resourse.customCSS, 'customCSS.css')}"/>
<body>
<h1>
<apex:sectionHeader title="Please Enter user information and upload LogFile"/>
</h1>
<apex:pagemessages />
<apex:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <apex:pageBlock >
      <apex:facet name="footer">
      <apex:outputPanel >
         <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Check and Upload" styleClass="btn"/>
      </apex:outputPanel>
      </apex:facet>
   <apex:pageBlockSection title="User Information">
      <apex:panelGrid columns="2">
         <apex:outputLabel value="First Name" for="inqueryFirstName"/>
         <apex:inputField id="inqueryFirstName" value="{!inquery.First_Name__c}" required="true"/>
         <apex:outputLabel value="Last Name" for="inqueryLastName"/>
         <apex:inputField id="inqueryLastName" value="{!inquery.Last_Name__c}"  required="true"/>
         <apex:outputLabel value="Email" for="inqueryEmail"/>
         <apex:inputField id="inqueryEmail" value="{!inquery.Email__c}"  required="true"/>
      </apex:panelGrid>
   </apex:pageBlockSection>
   <apex:pageBlockSection title="Upload File"  >
      <apex:panelGrid columns="2">
         <apex:outputLabel for="file"/>
         <apex:inputFile value="{!contentFile}" filename="{!nameFile}" id="file"/>
      </apex:panelGrid>
   </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</body>
</apex:page>
```

And i have a CSS file called customCSS.css
that has the following code:

```
<style type="text/css">

  body{
  padding-left: 11em;
   padding-right: 11em;
   padding-top: 5em;
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman",
        Times, serif;
  color: black;
   font-size: 12pt;
font-weight: 300;
text-align:justify;
   margin: 0em auto;
  width: 1200px;
  background-image: url("images/DSCN5018.gif")
}
  h1, h2, h3
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
}
p
{
margin-top: 1px;
line-height: 180%;
color: white
}

</style>
```

I have the css file in a folder called customCSS and inside the folder i have another folder called images.
And it has the an image called DSCN5018.gif
I zipped the folder called customCSS.zip,
and i uploaded the zip file  as follows

Name | Setup | Develop | Static Resources | New | Name as customCSS| Upload customCSS.zip |

I know this question is redundant,
And i am doing exactly what websites are advising,
But my page doesnt seem to change,

Does anyone know why?

Comment: You are missing ! before the URLFOR if adding ! does not fix the issue, try uploading just the CSS to the static resource and try : {!URLFOR($Resourse.customCSS)}

Comment: try to upload the css as static resource than picking it from a folder.

Comment: rao, that doesnt seem to work to

Comment: By the way rao, i got it to work without zipping the CSS file, so i uploaded the image separately and the CSS file separately, thanks

Comment: I always blame it on salesforce,but somewhere deep within I know its human error and not salesforce :P. Happy that it works for you when you try the CSS as a static resource and not trying to access from a folder in the SR.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo in the code.  You have misspelled Resource.  As well as the typo pointed out by Rao, you are missing a '!'

**Change**

```
<apex:stylesheet value="{URLFOR($Resourse.customCSS, 'customCSS.css')}"/>
```

**To**

```
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.customCSS, 'customCSS.css')}"/>
```

***EDIT:***

Another Typo.  No ';'

**Change**

```
background-image: url("images/DSCN5018.gif")
```

**To**

```
background-image: url("images/DSCN5018.gif");
```

***EDIT:***

You mention that images is a sub folder of customCSS, and you have no / to indicate that

**Change**

```
background-image: url("images/DSCN5018.gif");
```

**To**

```
background-image: url("/images/DSCN5018.gif");
```

Comment: Sorry for the typo, but it still doesn't work!!

Comment: Found another typo, updated the answer

Comment: Think I found another issue regarding the naming of the Resource.  I updated the code, try that

Comment: Dunc44, the MyStyles was a typo from me, i actually called it customCSS, i updated my question, sorry about that

Comment: Is that what you meant?

Comment: yes, thats what I meant.  You added the semi-colon also, to the line in the answer and that still didn't help?

Comment: What about adding a '/' to the background-image

background-image: url("/images/DSCN5018.gif");

Comment: @Dunc44 the `/` at the beginning of the background-image url shouldn't be necessary, as the `images` folder appears to be at the same level as the css file.

Comment: Same thing, still doesn't work

Comment: I just found out something strange, when i download the Styles.zip file from here [http://developer.force.com/workbook/styles] and upload the zip file, it works, when i modify the file using just my body part of the CSS and zip the file, it doesnt work anymore!!

Comment: There's a semicolon missing on the `p` styling too.

Comment: I have something to add, The stylus example I downloaded from this link [developer.force.com/workbook/styles] works fine, if I unzip the file and zip it again then upload it, it doesn't work anymore. Somehow my zip program is causing this, I am using WinRAR 4.22 (32-bit), and I use choose the ZIP option. Can you guys please tell me what you use to zip your folder? something you have used and it works.

Comment: I use WinZip and it works fine.  If you are looking for something that is free, I have also used ZipGenius, which also worked fine for me.  http://www.zipgenius.com/

Comment: I just tried ZipGenius, and it didn't work too, i don't get how unzipping and the zipping the file makes it fail!!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a zip file with a folder in it and in that folder is the CSS file you want to access.  Why not simplify and put the CSS file directly into the Zip file, with no added folder?  Otherwise, when you specify the name of the CSS file, you will need to precede it with the name of the containing folder (after specifying the zip file resource).

Hope this helps!

Comment: yes that's what i did, thnx